# Docker container host port not working but working in the container port

Tags: docker, port, docker-container, docker-image, docker-network

I am Not getting Output in the exposed port but got the output in the container port in the Docker container's shell. I am not able to find the root cause behind it.

I am using docker in a windows container environment.

I have created a docker image using the below docker file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

COPY ./PublishOutput/ /inetpub/wwwroot

# Give Full Access To Folder
RUN icacls 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot' /grant 'Everyone:(OI)(CI)F'
# Check that the files have been successfully copied
RUN dir
```

Create an image below command:

```
docker build -t projectimage .
```

After creating the image Details:

```
REPOSITORY    TAG     IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
                 
projectimage  latest  4654c6606bbd   4 days ago    9.06GB
```

From the above image, I have created a docker container.

Create a container below command:

```
docker container run -d -p 8080:80 -–name projectcontainer projectimage
```

After creating the container Details:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                   CREATED         STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
73abe46e99e9   projectimage   "C:\\ServiceMonitor.e…"   2 minutes ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   projectcontainer
```

Now, I go to the browser and try to access the container using the exposed port i.e 8080

```
http://localhost:8080
```

I get the "404 - File or directory not found." output on the browser screen.
below is the screenshot of the browser output.
[screenshot of the browser output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuQUp.png)

NetWork Details of container:

```
 "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "73abe46e99e9231b2d3ae67c436220e789b84990499b853310d4e9b1840b2118",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "80/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Now, I go into the Docker container's shell using the command

```
docker exec -it projectcontainer cmd.exe
```

Inside the Docker container's shell, I try to access the container using the container port i.e 80

```
curl localhost:80
```

and I got my output **" correctly configured to work"** which is the Expected Output.
below is the screenshot attached.
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNxhV.png)

So, why I am not getting the Expected output in the exposed port in the browser? How to Resolve this Problem.

Also, I am able to ping the host machine from the container and vice-versa.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This symptom often means you've configured the application inside the container to listen on something like `127.0.0.1:80`; it needs to listen on `0.0.0.0:80` or it will be unreachable from outside its own container.  If you're actually getting an HTTP 404 error (...with a PNG-format body?) then the Docker-level network wiring is probably correct.

Comment: David saved me.